# How to use xml element value in another xml file?

Tags: xml

I have two xml files :

```
1.) A.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <root>
        <version>2.0</version>
   </root>

2.) B.xml

   .....
   <Context path="/abc-2.0">
   </Context>
```

How can I use the value of element 'version' in B.xml instead of explicitly specifying '2.0'.
Both the xml's are at different path's.

Comment: read and parse first XML and update the parsed value in second XML. where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's impossible in plain XML. You may need to process your A.xml file to get the desired data.